# Camera Orientation is not displaying in proper mode

Tags: android, android-camera, android-orientation

I am trying to set orientation in portrait mode but I am trying to fixed it but it is not working.

Here's my code.

```
@Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {
        Log.i("cameraDemo", "Surface changed...");
    }

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i("cameraDemo", "Surface created, initializing camera...");
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.startPreview();
        Log.i("cameraDemo", "preview Started...");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("cameraDemo", e.toString());

    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    Log.i("cameraDemo", "camera released");
}
```

My question is:-

1. How do I fix it in portrait mode ?
2. Whenever I open camera, then it should be working only in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in an Activity? If so there are two ways- you can either specify this in the manifest (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) or in onCreate by adding the line

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

Answer (score 0):

you should check this repo https://github.com/pikanji/CameraPreviewSample.git out. Awesome resource/utility for Camera handling in Android. Helped me a lot once. ( it's not my project! )

Cheers